# Not allowing eventbridge/lambda to rerun the events which timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am using eventbridge to deliver events to my lambda. My lambda store the data associated with the event into the database. I also have one Eventbridge schedule which keep triggering this events every 15 mins.

Now issue is happening that suppose my lambda got event for Event A and it timeout due to too much data to process so it is trying to run it again. At the same time, my 15 min scheduler is trying to process the same event again as its still not completed.

I know there is a way that disable the retry but i dont to disable all the retry like in case of the target (lambda) not available or some other issues. I just want to target the rerun on the timeout. Though i can maintain state for the event bt my only worry is that if the lambda crashes or timeout before i try to change the state then my event will be left in invalid state.

**Is there a way that i can disable reruning the lambda on timeout on the event?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but I think the problem is that the EventBridge is retrying your event again (Not the lambda itself), so EventBridge sends an event to the lambda, it times out and since the EventBridge didn't acknowledge the event retry it again, after 15 min it send second event (while the first one is not done yet). so you should change EventBridge's retry policy instead of lambda's. check this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_RetryPolicy.html

Comment: EventBridge, incl. EventBridge Scheduler, invokes Lambda asynchronously. I.e., if the Lambda control plane accepts the event, EventBridge is out of the picture. Failures during event processing caused by the Lambda function (or underlying runtime) can lead to duplicate invocations from the Lambda control plane.

Comment: @HoseinRemezan i found out that its not that eventbridge invokes but lambda itself invokes the event again if it timeout. I tried setting "Retry attempts" to 0 in Asynchronous invocation in lambda config but no luck.

Comment: yes @MichaelGasch How to avoid that duplicate invocations? Though there are options like Lock that i set a property in redis cache to specify that event is getting processed so when next events comes then it checks the lock first if its not running

Issue with this approach that i feel it is kind of hack to make my lambda and eventbridge configuration works. Is there any approach you know which i can either configure on AWS or i can get a indicator from Eventbridge or lambda side that the event is in progress.!!!

Comment: @BhaskarDabhi Again I think lambda won't retry an Asynchronous event itself but if you've set the EventBridge retry attempts to 0 and the problem is still there, try to set 0 retry attempts for lambda according to this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-errors , Just remember this will turn off all retries from lambda and if you need to retry some specific type of errors then you need a dead letter queue.

Comment: You might want to check https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/typescript/latest/ which provides many options to handle idempotent operations w/out writing custom code.